# Get dynamically generated Controls of current Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a MasterPage website. I'll use the Facebook example to simplify understanding of my purpose.

In default.aspx, i add many DIVs dynamically from code-behind (ie. each div is a SQL result).

In each DIV there's a Label, and also a "Like" HyperLink, listened by a "onclick" JS function that changes "Like" to "Dislike" text in LinkButton and triggers an AJAX call that calls MyMethod(userid, postid) method.

The MyMethod() method changes the Like/Dislike status for the user in SQL.
I want MyMethod() to update the Label too, so MyMethod() would do:

```
        ((Label)((Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler).FindControl("lbl_XX")).Text = "foo";
```

The problem is that i can't get any of the controls of the page.

I also tried a EventHandler added to the LinkButton, but eventually the MyMethod() never gets the Label by FindControl because Page object seems to come without controls.

How can i access the controls of the current page from a method?

Comment: This AJAX call, is there an update panel involved?

Comment: No, it changes the Like/Dislike text and calls MyMethod() only. There is an UpdatePanel, but in a separate unrelated div.

Comment: It's a very bad pattern to get into to mix AJAX calls with calling the server to manipulate the client. Instead, in response to your AJAX call your server should return the text, and on the client side the label's text should be updated.

Comment: To elaborate on what @mason said: Your java script call to `MyMethod` only exists on the server and will not update anything on the client without further javascript to handle the response. `MyMythod` will not update the page. Also note that dynamically added controls are notoriously tricky to work with in ASP.NET. They have to be re-created and persisted every time, in a specific part of the page life cycle and there is a good chance this is not happening in `MyMethod`.

Comment: So, you are saying is IMPOSSIBLE in C# to get Page controls of the current page using FindControl() in a Method() if the event is trigerred by JavaScript? So i should turn this AJAX into a GET and use same script to change the Label? Or maybe turn it all into an UpdatePanel? No other way around?